# How to programmatically install a uninstalled Windows Gadget?

Tags: windows-desktop-gadgets

I have an installer that installs my_gadget.  The user then removes my_gadget from the gadget gallery and then try to run my installer again to re-install my_gadget.  However, I am unable to re-install my_gadget as it is now listed under PickerDefaultPackageSkipList="my_gadget," in sidebar's settings.ini file.

Is there any way to re-install my_gadget programmatically without having to modify settings.ini?